# Can I access files from a former employee's user account on OS X?

Tags: macos

I have several iMac G5s left in my office. They each had several users with passwords. I need to get information from them that may be in different areas; for example, a former employee had coded confidential files on his own desktop.

How do I get to these?

Comment: If the files are encrypted, you will *not* have access to them no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a situation like this before. Here is what I did to get in: (This will reset the password of the user of your choice. Use caution.)

First, boot the computer while holding Command + S until you see white text. This will boot the computer into Single User Mode, and will present you with a command prompt when everything is all loaded. Once you see the command prompt, type in each of these commands one by one, pressing enter after each one and waiting for the prompt to come up again before running the next one:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist
```

Now you will need to know the name of the User you want to access. If you are unsure, enter this command at the prompt and press enter to see a list of Users:

```
ls /Users
```

Once you know which User you want to change the password of, enter this command at the prompt and press enter (Replace USERNAME with the name of the User you want to change the password of, and PASSWORD with the new password):

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/USERNAME PASSWORD
```

For example:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/johndoe supersecure123
```

If everything seems okay, and there were no apparent errors, reboot the computer and login as the user you changed the password of, using the new password.

References: [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5681710/how-to-break-into-a-mac-and-prevent-it-from-happening-to-you)